# Github Actions Env variables not being read from os::env

Tags: rust, continuous-integration, github-actions

I'm still new to GitHub action. I'm compiling a CLI project with matrix build, I use `dotenv` in my project, which works locally with the .env file that I provide. The release matrix is used to bundle the binary for NPM. The workflow works, but the binary from the build that I tried from the NPM doesn't read the environment variables.

[The workflow file](https://github.com/smbpndk/smbpndk-cli/blob/development/.github/workflows/release-npm.yml).

I tried to log the env variables and they're there during the build process:

```
Run cargo build --release --locked --target x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
  cargo build --release --locked --target x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
  shell: /usr/bin/bash --noprofile --norc -e -o pipefail {0}
  env:
    RELEASE_VERSION: 0.1.9
    CARGO_INCREMENTAL: 0
    CARGO_TERM_COLOR: always
    CARGO_REGISTRIES_CRATES_IO_PROTOCOL: sparse
    GH_OAUTH_CLIENT_ID: ***
    GH_OAUTH_CLIENT_SECRET: ***
    Updating crates.io index
```

This is the code that reads them:

```
fn github_url_builder() -> URLBuilder {
    let client_id =
        env::var("GH_OAUTH_CLIENT_ID").unwrap_or("Please set GH_OAUTH_CLIENT_ID".to_owned());
    let redirect_uri =
        env::var("GH_OAUTH_REDIRECT_URI").unwrap_or("Please set GH_OAUTH_REDIRECT_URI".to_owned());

    let mut url_builder = URLBuilder::new();
    url_builder
        .set_protocol("https")
        .set_host("github.com")
        .add_param("client_id", &client_id)
        .add_param("redirect_uri", &redirect_uri);
    url_builder
}
```

Any clue?

Comment: Shouldn't you the binary be running to first to fetch the env vars? Where are you running it in your workflow?

Comment: Ah, it got me thinking. So you're saying the value of the env variables are not compiled together with the binary?

Comment: Found related thread: https://www.reddit.com/r/learnrust/comments/x34z8q/how_to_include_a_env_file_into_my_binary/

Comment: Well, you are fetching the values of env vars on runtime. Those env vars should exist to make it work. You can hardcode those inside your code if that's what you want. Regarding your above thread, looks like it's about embedding files as part of your binary. Not sure if that's what you want.

Comment: Yeah, I think there’s no other way than including those keys in the binary.